# Scala Play 2.3 Reactive CouchBase Connection problems with URI http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools

Tags: scala, playframework, couchbase

I have

```
couchbase {
  buckets = [{
    host="127.0.0.1"
    port="8091"
    base="pools"
    bucket="default"
    user="Administrator"
    pass="AdminAd"
    timeout="0"
  }]
}
```

In my config file - but on start up see

```
[info] ReactiveCouchbasePlugin - Starting ReactiveCouchbase plugin ...
2014-08-28 10:55:34.147 WARN com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP:  Connection problems with URI http : / /127...:8091/pools ...skipping
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
    at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readToString(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:423)
```

If I browse to http : / /127...:8091/pools I get a response

```
{"pools":[{"name":"default","uri":"/pools/default?uuid=3da344da ...
```

Any thoughts on what I've got wrong?

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password I was supplying was for the Admin web interface.

I actually didn't need to provide any password for this end point, as I've got everything open for testing